# VS2013\ TFS2010 build server getting a nuget error - after doing a nuget install

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, build-process, nuget-package-restore

I am having trouble setting up a Build Server for my asp.net mvc webapplication project.
I have set up the build server, I have installed the Visual Studio Redistribution packages.

I am using tfs2010 and VS2013.

```
Request Summary
Requested by TBSHOUSTON\brismi 49 seconds ago, Completed
Summary
Debug | AnyCPU
 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
$/TBS/Web/EtracsWeb/Mvc50/devExpress13.2/EtracsWeb/EtracsWeb.csproj - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s), View Log File
 C:\tbs2010Build\TBS\Web\EtracsWeb\Mvc50\devExpress13.2\EtracsWeb\EtracsWeb.csproj (3270): 
                   This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. 
                   Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  
                   For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317567.
 $/TBS/Web/EtracsWeb/Mvc50/devExpress13.2/EtracsWeb/EtracsWeb.csproj compiled
 No Test Results
 No Code Coverage Results
Other Errors and Warnings
 1 error(s), 1 warning(s)
 TF270015: 'MSBuild.exe' returned an unexpected exit code. Expected '0'; actual '1'.
```

Reading the blogs I read about getting rid of the pre-installed/MSBuild and I tried this.
I modified the .csproj file to get rid of the nuget.targets and I got rid of the nuget.exe and
the nuget.targets

this did not work

I next did a manual install of the nuget packages on the build server.... The install process
worked and it appears all of the packages installed...So I thought great and reran the build
server...and receive the same error....

I don't understand what I am missing....having done the install manually I would think the
process would work, but it doesn't...

Another question... How do you add a command-line command to the build process?  I don't see
where in the edit build process you can add a command-line command.